# Match Multiple URL Paths with Apache Camel CXF Endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, apache-camel

We are using Apache Camel with CXF endpoints to process our web service requests. What I'd like to be able to do is have my application be able to accept messages on any URL like:

```
http://localhost:9000/[anything]/MyService
http://localhost:9000/foo/MyService
http://localhost:9000/bar/MyService
```

I think I could make this a configurable setting, but I would much rather have it be completely dynamic and accept any path component before my service name. I've read about the [Camel URL Rewrite Component](http://camel.apache.org/urlrewrite.html) and it seems like that may work, but it didn't feel like the right answer.

If it helps here is my endpoint configuration (with some details removed for brevity):

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="MessageEndpoint"
                serviceClass="MyClass"
                serviceName="RespondingGateway_PortType"
                address="{{web-service-url}}:{{port}}/subpath/MyService">

</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

What I'd like to be able to do is put something like `/*/subpath/MyService` in the address property to match on anything, but this doesn't work.